# Orderby syntax ASC

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

What is the correct syntax to order by ASC
?

Error   1   The name 'ASC' does not exist in the current context

```
 public IEnumerable<DTO> GetGrid(String ShipNumber)
    {
        try
        {
            ORepository rep = new ORepository();
            var query = rep.GetAll()
                .Where(x => x.SHIP == ShipNumber)
                .Orderby (x.City ASC)
                .Select(g => new DTO
                {
                    CUSTOMER_NAME = g.CUSTOMER_NAME,
                    CITY = g.CITY,
                    SHIP = g.SHIP,
                });

            return query;
```

Answer (score 56, accepted):

- `.OrderBy(x => x.City)` for ascending order.
- `.OrderByDescending(x => x.City)` for descending order

Comment: Short and simple. Thanks!

Comment: Bear in mind outta there that this is actually returning an IOrderedEnumerable<T> instead of modifying the IEnumerable itself!

Answer (score 1):

Use this query when you use Distinct.

```
var result = ctx.tblCity.AsNoTracking()
 .Where(s => s.City== "Chennai")                                 
 .Select(s => new Area { Name = s.AreaName})                                 
 .Distinct().OrderBy(s => s.Name).ToList();
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
IEnumerable<t_HomeRequets> homeRequets = cnx.t_HomeRequets
    .Where(x => x.HomeRequestId > DeletedId && x.BuildingId== BuildingId)
    .OrderByDescending(s => s.HomeRequestId)
    .AsEnumerable<t_HomeRequets>();
```

Outputs an IEnumerable set
you can create this set with a var or any type